# How to link internal port to outside port in docker?

Tags: docker

I am not sure if I understand the docker port concept. Say I have an application inside a container that listens on port 6000 for tcp  connections. This container is on server A.

I want to connect to the application from another server B. But I want to start multiple instances of the same container on server A and the internal port should stay 6000. However the external port should change.

E.g

```
container 1 6000->9660
container 2 6000->9661
...
```

So from outside the application should expose 9660, 9661,... Is this possible? I tried with:

```
docker run -p 9660:6000 ...
```

however the client could not connect. Any ideas?

Comment: Unless you need to expose the port from container A to the outside, for some reason, you should use [linked containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) instead.. it is more secure.  By linking Container B to Container A, it sets environment variables in Container B that point to the IP address and port in Container A. You then use those vars in your app.  This way, the ports aren't exposed to the outside world.

Comment: @transistor1 +1 thanks for the info, however in my use case they have to be exposed to the outside world.

Comment: Understood, my mistake... I read your question to mean that you were linking 2 containers together, but re-reading it it actually says "server B" rather than "container"

Comment: Note there is the -P argument to docker run which automatically assign a free high numbered port for each exposed port in the container - might save you some hassle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to

```
EXPOSE 6000
```

inside my Dockerfile. Now it works :)